# Where is English training/dev data for spaCy's pretrained dependency parser?

Tags: nlp, dataset, spacy

Does spaCy publicly release the dev/test data for their pretrained dependency parser (en_core_web_sm/md/lg), and if so where can it be accessed?

For context: I'm trying to measure the pretrained parser's accuracy *on a particular kind of sentence* (not just an entire treebank like Penn Treebank), and so I need gold labeled sentences from the dev set or test set so that I can identify the type of sentence and evaluate. I would use another dependency treebank like a Universal Dependencies treebank, but unfortunately the annotation schemes are slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

It is [OntoNotes 5](https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC2013T19) as mentioned at [spaCy models repo at Github](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/tag/en_core_web_sm-2.3.1).

Comment: Thanks! I looked at OntoNotes 5.0, but unfortunately it doesn't include dependency parse data. Instead, it's in PTB constituency format. Is spaCy's dependency training data converted from these constituency parses?

Comment: You may like to explore corpus given at [Universal Dependencies](https://universaldependencies.org/) or use the mappings mechanisms. Please see https://github.com/UniversalDependencies/tools/issues/31.